# Зачем нужен унарный плюс в python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, операции

Возник следующий вопрос: зачем в питоне нужен унарный плюс? Что он делает такого, что нельзя было бы сделать без него?

```
>>> x = -5
>>> +x
-5
>>> 3
3
>>> +3
3
>>> +-3
-3
```

Получается, что справедливо выражение

```
+x = x
```

при любом числе `x` (в том числе отрицательном).

Так что же делает унарный плюс?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16819023/whats-the-purpose-of-the-pos-unary-operator-in-python

Comment: Он разрешает литералы вида +1. Он кое-что делает полезное для нечисел. Если разговор только о числах и без литералов, он не делает ничего.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, а зачем нужны литералы вида +1?

Comment: Вам иногда приходится читать их из файлов. Питон не должен быть хуже других языков. Другие языки разрешают явный плюс в литералах.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, а для нечисел что он делает?

Comment: Для нечисел-контейнеров он обязан изготовить копию объекта. Для некоторых нечисел он делает приведение к целым. Почитайте ссылку выше. Можете даже перевести всё что там найдете и сделать самоответ. Будет куча плюсиков.

Comment: Есть еще вариант с перегрузкой операторов

Comment: Легально ли просто взять и перевести ответы с enSO с указанием авторов?

Comment: @Acinit, речь не идёт о дословном переводе. Там факты разбросаны по нескольким ответам. Перевести, снабдить ссылками и опубликовать как одну сводку.

Comment: @Acinit, отвечая на ваш вопрос. Да, переводы с указанием источника разрешены. https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11523

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Когда `x != +x`?

Примеры из стандартной библиотеки

1. `decimal.Decimal` при изменении точности:

   ```py
   >>> import decimal
   >>> ctx = decimal.getcontext()
   >>> ctx.prec = 40
   >>> one_third = decimal.Decimal('1') / decimal.Decimal('3')
   >>> one_third
   Decimal('0.3333333333333333333333333333333333333333')
   >>> one_third == +one_third
   True
   >>> ctx.prec = 28  # меняем точность
   >>> one_third == +one_third
   False
   >>> +one_third
   Decimal('0.3333333333333333333333333333')
   ```
2. В классе `collections.Counter` унарный `+` убирает ключи с отрицательными значениями:

   ```py
   >>> from collections import Counter
   >>> ct = Counter('abracadabra')
   >>> ct
   Counter({'a': 5, 'r': 2, 'b': 2, 'd': 1, 'c': 1})
   >>> ct['r'] = -3
   >>> ct['d'] = 0
   >>> ct
   Counter({'a': 5, 'b': 2, 'c': 1, 'd': 0, 'r': -3})
   >>> +ct
   Counter({'a': 5, 'b': 2, 'c': 1})
   >>> ct == +ct
   False
   ```

<sub>Взято из книги Fluent Python, 2nd ed., by
Luciano Ramalho (O’Reilly). Copyright 2022 Luciano Ramalho, 978-1-492-05635-5.</sub>